# check if element hasClass added with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

On my blog theme I have a "SHOW MORE POST" button after the last post of the page.
When the user clicks the button, more posts are loaded without refreshing the page.
I am doing this using the "Ajax Load More" plugin from the Wordpress repository.
When there are no more post to load, I would like to hide this button.

When there are no more posts, the button becomes a class of ".done", added by ajax.

I have been trying to hide the button using jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var morebutton = $("button#load-more");

    if ( $(morebutton).hasClass("done") ) {
        $(this).hide();
    }

});
```

but I am having no result. I think i have the right selectors. I have tryed to hide it on a click and it works. I used this jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var morebutton = $("button#load-more");

    $(morebutton).click(function(){
        if ( $(this).hasClass("done") ) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

 });
```

So, my question is how can I check if an element hasClass, if this class is dynamically added with AJAX?

When I use the document.ready function it will check my element only on document.ready. Is this correct?
So how could i check also after an ajax event?

Any other ways to hide the button after all posts are loaded?

Thank you!

Comment: It's `morebutton.hasClass("done")` without `$()`

Comment: ah, yes, of course. thanks! But it still doesn't work. i can see in Inspector that the button becomes the "done" class, but the button doesn't hide.

Comment: use `$("#load-more")`, there is no need for 'button' in selection.

Answer (score 1):

`morebutton` is already a jquery object, so, you don't need to wrap again.

```
$(function() {
    var morebutton = $("button#load-more");
    morebutton.click(function(){
        if ( $(this).hasClass("done") ) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, thanks.
With a click with works fine. What i am trying to do is make the button hide without clicking...

Comment: Then your ajax callback/plugin callback should throw a flag, something like, `hasMorePosts = true|false` and then based on the flag, you could hide/show the button.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to do this when ajax is done, so you should do this, in the ajax success or done:

```
$.ajax({
    url: whatever
})
.done(function( data ) {
    var morebutton = $("#load-more");

    //if ( morebutton.hasClass("done") ) { it is done now, check for something else, or just hide
        morebutton.hide();
    //}
});
```

You could define a global success like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    var morebutton = $("#load-more");

    if ( morebutton.hasClass("done") ) { 
        morebutton.hide();
    }
});
```

see here for more information: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Comment: Each time i click the button it adds more post.
After the LAST posts are added i would like to hide the button...   :/

Comment: I dont know this plugin, do you have access to the ajax call .js?

Comment: there are so many .js files inside the plugin folder...   =/
But i just found out how to do it using just css. Thanks!

Comment: It seams that the .ajaxSuccess() would be a good way to do it using jQuery. But i think i will stick with the easier and simpler CSS solution. but thanks, it's always nice to learn different ways of doing things!  =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out i was trying to make it much more complicated than it had to be.

Instead of using jQuery i just used CSS.
I added a rule like this:

```
#load-more.done {
    display: none;
}
```

...and now it's working nicely!

Thanks for your help, though!  =)